# URL with Parameters

Tags: php, url, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I have got my url parameters working via the form however I am having trouble passing params via the url.

I am currently posting my query in the url via the get method.  I can then retreive this parameter via the params function below.

```
$search_industry = (int) $this->params()->fromQuery('search_industry', 0);
```

I have two issues with the url currently

First: The parameters are posting based on order as opposed to based on the name I have given them in the module config.  In my config 'search industry' is first however if I pass a language and no industry the language param becomes an industry param.

```
module config param

                    'results' => array(
                        'type' => 'segment',
                        'options' => array(
                            'route' => 'results[/:search_industry][/:search_zip][/:language_name]
                            'defaults' => array(
                                'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Index',
                                'action'     => 'results',
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
```

**What is happening**

```
    when...
    search industry = null
    language name = english

url = results/english

    search industry = english
    language name = 0
```

Because of this I have build my url out as the following...

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->url('home/results',
            array(
                'search_industry'=>'0',
                'search_zip'=>'0',
                'language_name'=>'3'
                )
             );?>"> <?php echo $language->language_name  ?> </a>
```

Second:
This post the url as a segment.  Using post on my forms I am able to get a url like below

```
results?search_industry=&search_zip=&submit=Go
```

How can I use post on the url?  I see it has 2 other variables ($routeOptions, $reuseMatchedParams) but I can't find much info on them.  I am passing the variables to a form, and searching based on the params.  Thank you for the input.

Comment: You are confusing route params and query params. If you want to build an url with query param, you have to concat your query string to your generated url, ex : <a href="<?php echo $this->url('home/results'); ?>?search_industry=0&search_zip=0&language_name=3">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above comment is spot on!  Below is what I updated to...

```
 <td>        <a href="<?php echo $this->url('home/results',
        array(
            ),array('query' => ['language_name' => $language->language_name_id],)
         );?>"> <?php echo $language->language_name  ?> </a>
```